# Android set edittext max limit in bytes

Tags: android, android-edittext

In android, I want an edit text with limit of 255 bytes, so when the user will try to exceed this limit, it won't let him to write.

All the filters I saw are using characters limit, even in the xml layout.

So how can I set a filter to the edittext in order to limit to 255 bytes?

Comment: Well you could just calc its byte size on user input, but doesnt have all chars the same byte size in the same encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be.

- Use a TextWatcher on the EditText to get a String of the typed text.
- Use myString.getBytes().length; to get the size of the string in bytes.
- perform an action on the EditText based on a threshold you have set in bytes.

  ```
  final int threshold = 255;
  EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          int i = s.toString().getBytes().length;
          if(i < threshold){
              //Action needed
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      }
  });
  ```

You will need to apply this example to your own solution.

Answer (score -1):

One Charterer (char) is of 2 bytes, if you set the android:maxlength="128" in your editText, you will get the limit you want

```
                            <EditText

                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:maxLength="128"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: Hi, I checked with string.getBytes().length each character and i found that in english, each characters is represented by 1 byte, but hebrew characters are represented by 2 bytes. so, if i set the max length to 128, the user would be able to input 64 letters, but this is not the case, it enables him to input 128 chars even if he types in hebrew